# Sound is distort on iPad when using web audio api

Tags: javascript, ios, html5-video, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I have a problem when I am trying to play on iPad an mp3 using the web audio api.
In fact, the application is a html page where I try to play some mp3 or video files. 
If I play first a video and then an mp3 file, the mp3 sound is distort.
If I play first a mp3 file everything work fine.

Even if all the video and audio have the same sample rate is not working.

Do you have any idea what should I do to avoid sound distortion?

Comment: Can you post a jsbin or jsfiddle example that demonstrates the problem you're experiencing?